# How to take only part of the javascript timestamp

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, unix-timestamp

I have a js timestamp of `Tue Sep 30 2014 12:02:50 GMT-0400 (EDT)`

with .getTime() I got `1412092970.768`

for most cases, its a today's specific time stamp. I wonder, if I could always ONLY pick out the day month and year and hour, min, day will be always stay with 0.

So for our situation, it should become `Tue Sep 30 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)`.

I wonder what kind of conversion should I be doing? Because seem convert to unix timestamp with getTime() will result in unknown way of calculation... and I can not really find a way to set time like I would do in PHP.

Any fix for this situation?

Thanks

Comment: So change the date object to set it to the exact time of day that you want. You'll find out how if you read [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: `.getTime()` should yield `1412092970768` - it's milliseconds in javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a date object and then zero-out any components you don't need, or create one with the components you specified, e.g.

```
foo = new Date();
foo.setHour(0);
foo.setMinute(0);
```

or something more like

```
foo = new Date(); // "now"

bar = new Date(foo.getYear(), foo.getMonth(), foo.getDate(), 0 , 0, 0, 0);
// create new date with just year/month/day value, and time zeroed-out.
```

The constructor's args are detailed here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 0):

An other option is to send epoch to PHP:

JS:

```
long epoch = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
```

PHP:

```
   $dt = new DateTime("@$epoch");   
   $dt->format('Y'); //year
```